# Rails custom validate method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem, ancestry

I'm using the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) in order to create subcategories. After that when I create an item (item model) I use the following group select in order to associate the item with the subcategories it belongs to. The group select has the categories and subcategories grouped together.

```
<%= form.input :category, collection: @categories, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :children, label: false, include_blank: true %>

@categories = Category.where(ancestry: nil).order('name ASC')
```

Also I'm using the the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) in order to create and thus associate many subcategories to an item.

Now I would like to add a custom`validate` method inside a model which will allow the user to only add subcategories that belong to the same main category, or otherwise return an error:

```
errors.add(:category, "you can only choose subcategories from he same category")
```

I'm kind of stuck on how to create this `validate` method. Maybe first I should find the subcategories that are being added:

```
subcategory = Category.find(category)
```

And then find the category that the subcategory belongs to with this:

```
subcategory.root.name
```

But after that I have now idea what to do.

How can I create this `validate` method in order to allow the user to only add subcategories that belong to the same main category, or otherwise return an error?

Thank you in advance. Help would be very much appreciated on this one.

Comment: Should this instead be a validation?

Comment: @Schwern... turns out that it was a validate method and not a before save method. But still, I don't have an idea on how to finalize the validate method.

Comment: You want to ensure all the categories an item belongs to are all subcategories of the same parent? Can you give an example of failing this validation?

Comment: I have a column inside the category table named ancestry. If the ancestry column is nil then it is a main category, if it has a number then its a subcategory and it belongs to that category number. So basically a validation failing would be: When I add fields with cocoon in order to associate the item with subcategories(the number of fields could be from 1-10), upon submission of the form and if the ancestry number of each subcategory doesn't match then return the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, all Categories assigned to an Item must be subcategories of the same Category. And I assume they have to be subcategories.

Write a [custom validation method](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) in Item which verifies all the subcategories have parents, and all the subcategories are the same.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many categories

  validate :categories_have_the_same_parent

  private def categories_have_the_same_parent
    if categories.any? { |cat| !cat.ancestry_id }
      errors.add(
        :categories,
        :not_a_subcategory,
        "All categories must be sub-categories"
      )
    end

    if categories.each_cons(2).any? { |a,b| a.ancestry_id != b.ancestry_id }
      errors.add(
        :categories,
        :different_ancestors,
        "All categories must have the same parent."
      }
    end
  end
end
```

The diagnostics on this can be improved to include the offending categories.

Then, in the form, populate the Item with the form information and check the Item's validation as normal.

```
class ItemController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @item = Item.create!(...params...)

    ...creation succeeded...
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    ...creation failed...
  end
end
```